# R - Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection to

Tags: r

I'm new to R and my current assignment is to write a simple package. I was trying to "set up a Github actions"(this is what the instruction says). I first used:

```
usethis::use_readme_md()
```

Everything works fine. But when I used this line of code:

```
usethis::use_github_action_check_standard()
```

the following error shows up:

```
Error in file(con, "r") : 
  cannot open the connection to 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/r-lib/actions/master/examples/check-standard.yaml'
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") :
  URL 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/r-lib/actions/master/examples/check-standard.yaml': status was 'Couldn't connect to server'
```

I'm not sure what to do. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried updating the package? Looking through the history of the package (https://github.com/r-lib/usethis/commits/main/R/github-actions.R) suggests they've changed the file location on where the actions are being stored -- so that may be the source of the error.

I had the same error but after updating to the latest package version it went away.